# How can i change selected date color in Date picker in android?

Tags: android, datepicker, customization

I am using this code for date Picker .. i want set color of selected date differnt. and change default color of text in date picker. How can i perform it. I am using android2.2 .

```
  <LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/datePickerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.45"
    android:background="#2B2B2B" >

    <DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="27dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:maxDate="@string/maxDate"
        android:minDate="@string/minDate" >
    </DatePicker>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In order to have access to the internals of the DatePicker your going to have to include a custom version of the class.  If you look at the source you'll notice 3 EditTexts and they are all private with no public getters... The good news is the class is fairly simple so modifying it should be a easy.

http://androidxref.com/4.2.2_r1/xref/frameworks/base/core/java/android/widget/DatePicker.java#95

Answer (score 0):

The idea is to loop on children of DatePicker to obtain NumberPickers. Once we get the NumberPicker, obtain private field mSelectorWheelPaint of type Paint (which is used to paint the DatePicker), and set it's color.

Just use next code and call `updateAttrs(yourDatePicker, color)`:

```
void updateAttrs(ViewGroup p, int color) {
    for (int i = 0; i < p.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View v = p.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof NumberPicker)
           setNumberPickerColor((NumberPicker)v, color);
        else if (v instanceof ViewGroup)
            updateAttrs((ViewGroup)v, color);
    }
}

void setNumberPickerColor(NumberPicker p, int color) {
    try {
        Field selectorWheelPaintField = NumberPicker.class.getDeclaredField("mSelectorWheelPaint");
        if (selectorWheelPaintField != null) {
            selectorWheelPaintField.setAccessible(true);
            ((Paint) selectorWheelPaintField.get(p)).setColor(color);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("YourTag", e.getMessage(), e);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < p.getChildCount(); ++i) {
        View v = p.getChildAt(i);
        if (v instanceof EditText)
            ((EditText) v).setTextColor(color);
    }

    p.invalidate();
}
```

Probably you will need system version >= 21 (Lollipop), but I didn't try.